# Get highest number in a string that's inside an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, object

I want to clone an object, but then I need to assign a new ID on the object.

The problem is that the object has named the ID's as a string. And I need to increase the number by each clone I make, to avoid conflicts.

```
Obj = [
    {_name:"Jane", _id:"_per1"},
    {_name:"Jonas", _id:"_per2"},
    {_name:"Joakim", _id:"_per3"},
    {_name:"Johanna", _id:"_per4"}
    ]
```

When I clone one of these. I want to change the '_id' on the clone so it's higher than, in this case '_per4'.

Therefore I want to be able to extract the highest number from '_id' in 'Obj'.

This I have been using to extract the number from '_id'.

```
var maxID = Obj._id.replace() /^\D+/g, '');
```

I have also tried this

```
Math.max.apply(Math,Obj.map(function(o){return o._id;}))
```

But that does not work. Think it's because '_id' is a string and not an int.

Help appreciated!

Comment: It would make more sense - and be much easier - to store them in order in the array, then use the index of the item to add any numerical values to the `id`. Hacking around a string to make part of its value incremental is always a pain that causes more work for very little/no benefit

Comment: can you provide your output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.replace("_per","")` in `.map()` methos as below ...

```js
$(function(){
Obj = [
    {_name:"Jane", _id:"_per1"},
    {_name:"Jonas", _id:"_per2"},
    {_name:"Joakim", _id:"_per3"},
    {_name:"Johanna", _id:"_per4"}
    ]
    
    var d = Math.max.apply(Math,Obj.map(function(o){
        return o._id.toString().replace("_per","");
    }));
    alert('max id is :- ' + d)
    
    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please run code snippet ........ **It is Working ... !**

Comment: @sumpen - please check above answer ... it can help you

Comment: This is working for me. And by far the cleanest. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// If you have 
var Obj = {
_per1:"Jane",
_per2:"Jonas",
_per3:"Joakim",
_per4:"Johanna"
} 

//then you can do 

console.log(Object.keys(Obj).sort().pop())
```

If you have more than 9, you will need to add a function to the sort to remove the _per and parseInt when sorting

Answer (score 0):

Well if the `_id` respects always the form  `_perX`, you can use the following code:

```
var lastIndex = 0;

Obj.forEach(function(el){
   var ind = parseInt(el["_id"].substring(el["_id"].lastIndexOf("r")+1));
   if(ind>lastIndex){
       lastIndex = ind;
   }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
Obj = [
    {_name:"Jane", _id:"_per1"},
    {_name:"Jonas", _id:"_per2"},
    {_name:"Joakim", _id:"_per30"},
    {_name:"Johanna", _id:"_per4"}
    ];
    
var lastIndex = 0;

Obj.forEach(function(el){
   var ind = parseInt(el["_id"].substring(el["_id"].lastIndexOf("r")+1));
   if(ind>lastIndex){
       lastIndex = ind;
   }
});

console.log(lastIndex);
```

**Note:**

- It will extract the last index from the `_id` using the `substring()`
  and `lasIndexOf()` methods in
  `el["_id"].substring(el["_id"].lastIndexOf("r")+1)`.
- This will also work with indexes  higher than `10`.
- I used `parseInt()` to parse the extracted index so it gives the right result in comparison, because if you write `"30">4` it will give you `false`, if `"30"` is a `string`.